# Is it possible to change text formatting in BibLaTeX conditionally?

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I want only article titles in a foreign language to be italicized. Is it possible to impose such a condition with `BibLaTeX`?

Comment: Hi, please add an example (minimal but complete and compilable) of what you need. "Foreign language" is probably something that's different for any reader... https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography can help.

Comment: This could be not a good idea if the journal names and/or  book titles are also italicized automatically and/or there are scientific names  emphasized   manually.  Add one more criteria to add italics  could make the references style unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to indicate somehow that the article is in a different language from the main document.

I think I'd do this by adding a `langid` field to the bib entry and testing for this in the `title` format.

#### Notes

- I've used `babel` with default language `american` and secondary language `ngerman`.
- I've used the `biblatex` option `autolang=hyphen` so that hyphenation for references in German is correct, but language of references remains in English.
- I've added `langid={ngerman}` to the German reference.
- My example is for a `book` entry type (I happened to have some useful bib entries lying around). But the principles are the same for `article` entry types.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{wellhausen:1883,
  author = {Wellhausen, Julius},
  title = {Prolegomena zur Geschichte Israels},
  edition = {2},
  location = {Berlin},
  publisher = {Reimer},
  date = {1883},
  langid = {ngerman}
}
@book{wellhausen:1885,
  author = {Wellhausen, Julius},
  title = {Prolegomena to the History of Israel},
  translator = {Black, J. Sutherland and Enzies, A.},
  preface = {Smith, W. Robertson},
  location = {Edinburgh},
  publisher = {Black},
  related = {wellhausen:1883},
  relatedtype = {translationof},
  date = {1885}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{%
  \iffieldundef{langid}
    {#1}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}%
  }
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

More sophisticated tests could be used if sometimes you had `langid = {american}` in your bib entry.

[image: output]

Comment: I'd almost be tempted to use `language` instead of `langid` here. But of course `language` usually appears in the output, so that might not be to everyone's liking. (The `clearlang` option would help with titles that are in the document language, though.)